# Communality and specific variance of observations in factor analysis

Tags: variance, factor-analysis

I am new to factor analysis and I am a bit confused. In theory, it seems that we can partition the variance of each observation into communality and specific variance. However, in any example, people seem to calculate the communalities and specific variances of the variables (and not the observations). Is there a way to get the communalities and specific variances of the observations? Am I missing something?
Thank you !

Comment: The two variances pertain to a variable. How can an observation (an individual, for example) have variability? what do you mean saying it has it?

Comment: yes I think the question was not very clear. observations do not have variations. I wanted to see if there is a way to get the communality and the specific variance fro a group of observations (eg. a certain country)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for Q-technique factor analysis (FA), which decomposes the data in terms of common people (or types of people) instead of common items. Put differently, traditional (R-technique) FA defines rows to be people and columns to be the variable. Q-technique does the opposite. Thompson (2004) provides an excellent non-technical description of Q-technique FA.

**References**

Thompson, B. (2004). Exploratory and confirmatory factor analysis. American Psychological Association.